# Symfony Return child objects depend of some property

Tags: symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

Im using Symfony 4 + Api Platform. I have an entity (Insurance) that it is relationed with another entity (MediaObject). When I try to GET some item of Insurance, it is returning all the MediaObjects items that they are relationed with it. However, I dont want to return all the MediaObjects. I need MediaObjects where deletedAt is null.

How can I fix that?

I have a DoctrineExtension where I coded:

```
$queryBuilder->join(sprintf('%s.mediaObjects', $rootAlias), 'mo');
$queryBuilder->andWhere(sprintf('%s.deletedAt IS NULL', $rootAlias));
$queryBuilder->andWhere('mo.deletedAt IS NULL');
```

but nothing happens. It is still returning all items.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "mediaObjects": [
      {
        "id": 5,
        "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
        "type": "INSURANCE",
        "createdAt": "2018-07-20T09:36:05+02:00",
        "updatedAt": "2018-07-20T09:36:05+02:00",
        "deletedAt": "2018-07-20T14:20:34+02:00"
      },
      {
        "id": 10,
        "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
        "type": "INSURANCE",
        "createdAt": "2018-07-20T11:01:38+02:00",
        "updatedAt": "2018-07-20T14:04:42+02:00",
        "deletedAt": "2018-07-20T14:20:34+02:00"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
        "type": "INSURANCE",
        "createdAt": "2018-07-20T09:35:56+02:00",
        "updatedAt": "2018-07-20T14:04:00+02:00",
        "deletedAt": "2018-07-20T14:15:09+02:00"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
        "type": "INSURANCE",
        "createdAt": "2018-07-20T09:36:13+02:00",
        "updatedAt": "2018-07-20T14:15:49+02:00",
        "deletedAt": null
      }
    ],
    "expirationDate": "2018-07-19T08:25:29+02:00",
    "policy": "Verduras",
    "producerName": "Aseguradoras S.L.",
    "contactEmail": "testsingfact+aseguradora1@gmail.com",
    "contactPhone": "700000001",
    "quantity": 1200,
    "type": "CARGO",
    "coverageExceptions": "Caidas",
    "createdAt": "2018-07-19T10:27:22+02:00",
    "updatedAt": "2018-07-19T13:06:31+02:00",
    "deletedAt": null
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you add to the question full query code instead of those 3 lines? Also, It will be very useful if you add to the question the result of `$queryBuilder->getDQL()`.

Comment: I have not access to the query, I mean, the query is on the Api Platform core. I suppose that I can add some sentences to redefine that query with a DoctrineExtesion (https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extensions/) and that is those lines.

Anyway, I'll print $queryBuilder->getDQL() tomorrow and paste it here.

Comment: ok. Wait for your DQL

Comment: I finally got the dql with your command and the sentence is "SELECT o, mediaObjects_a1 FROM App\Entity\App\Insurance o LEFT JOIN o.mediaObjects mediaObjects_a1 WHERE o.corporate = :corporate AND o.deletedAt IS NULL ORDER BY o.id ASC".

Based on this, I added                $queryBuilder->andWhere('mediaObjects_a1.deletedAt IS NULL'); and this is working now ^^. Thanks.

Anyway, I dont know if this is the best approach because I dont know if the alias "mediaObjects_a1" will be the same for all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use conditional join and apply filter to the joining collection not to the whole set:

```
$queryBuilder->join(sprintf('%s.mediaObjects', $rootAlias), 'mo', 'WITH', 'mo.deletedAt IS NULL');
$queryBuilder->andWhere(sprintf('%s.deletedAt IS NULL', $rootAlias));
```

Keep in mind this query will not return insurance entities that do not have non-deleted media objects because of `join`. If you want it to also return objects with empty media collection change `join` to `leftJoin`